# How to avoid privilege escalation in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to figure out how to implement three contradicting requirements in AWS

1. Have a few admins with privileged access to IAM, Lambda, VPC, RDS and EC2.
2. Keep secret data in SSM Parameter Store that no one except my app can read.
3. Let admins create and deploy my app.

Things to keep in mind - since my app should be able to read the secret there is an IAM role and policies that grant access to it.

I can deny admins access to the Parameter Store. But that would not stop them from assuming my app role and reading the secret data. What makes it worse is many ways to assume role:

1. AssumeRole API.
2. Create EC2 Instance, assign role, login and read secrets under EC2 instance role.
3. Same with AWS Lambda.
4. If I deny access to the role they can Create a new role with right set of policies.
5. If I deny access to policies then they can replicate them.
6. If I deny access to IAM admins cannot do their job.

Given that many privilege escalation paths how do I protect secret data in AWS?

Comment: The only way to do this is get rid of admins. This is _theoretically_ possible, by automating all deployment processes. But it's far better to hire admins that you trust.

Comment: yoh need to understand the meaning of administration, they should have highest privilege to maintain your account, and that why they are there. you prob is different, if i understand it correctly you have some data in param store which only available to your application. then you can simply encript the data  and store it into param store then read the data through your app and decript it before use. in this way even anyone has access the datA they will not get the actual value.

Comment: @MrOverflow If I encrypt then app has to read decryption key from somewhere (Param Store, KMS, Secrets Manager). And I back to square one - now I need to keep decryption key secret.

Comment: exactly, if are storing any key in some place then someone need to get access of it. it your admin has a role to access SSM then he/she will able to get that.  but if you encrypt that using KMS then it's not displaced as human readable format.  it's up to you where you are storing some key and who already have access to that box.