# Can I escalate my privileges if I have read-write access to IAM service in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, cloud, amazon-iam, privileges

We are trying to convince folks in our company to grant developers full privileges to all services  in "dev" account (current policy does not allow developers to create anything in our AWS account, because "security").

Folks say we might grant you full privileges to certain services e.g. S3, but some services (specifically IAM) will be off limits. Argument is users would be able to grant themselves all kind of permissions if they have read/write access to IAM service in our account.

In following scenario:

- There are two S3 buckets (`s1` and `s2`) in an AWS account.
- User `thekashyap` is granted full control over `s1`, but not `s2` (se he can't see/read/write/access/manage `s2` at all).
- User `thekashyap` is granted full control over IAM service.

Questions:

1. Can `thekashyap` grant himself access to `s2` by doing something in IAM?
2. Can `thekashyap` create a new IAM user that has access to `s2`?
3. If answer to either 1 or 2 is yes, then is there a way to prevent it other than revoking all IAM privileges of `thekashyap`?

---

I've read:

- [Limiting other AWS IAM roles from interacting with resources/privilege escalation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71230412/limiting-other-aws-iam-roles-from-interacting-with-resources-privilege-escalatio)
- [How to avoid privilege escalation in AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70580724/how-to-avoid-privilege-escalation-in-aws)

and a few more..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this question (and probably the other ones as well) could be better asked at [security.se].

Comment: "User thekashyap is granted full control over IAM service." That's basically the definition of a full system admin in AWS. That user would be able to grant themselves any and all permissions. There is really no difference between that user, and a user with ALL permissions in the AWS account. It's like a Linux user with `sudo` permission. Don't give full IAM permissions to people who shouldn't have all IAM permissions.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, is there a way I can move the question instead of posting a new one there?

Comment: Yesno, you can not do this yourself, but you can flag a moderator to ask for migration if your question has already been answered (otherwise you could just cut / paste the question of course).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I flagged it as you suggested, and they just closed it! Thanks anyway.

Comment: Eh, sorry about that. But migration on the [se] network is a bit fickle, and there are lots of reasons why it may not work. I see you got your answer anyway :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, not your fault, just venting. Yes, got some clarity here, but I posted it on Info Sec also with some additional info. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the user can grant access to any and all S3 buckets.
2. Yes, the user can create new IAM Users that can access any and all buckets (and anything else in the AWS Account).
3. You could be *very specific* about which IAM access can be granted (eg can only put users in specific IAM Groups) but that would probably take away the reason why you wanted to have IAM access in the first place.

Either the account needs to be "anyone can do anything" (with the result that somebody else might modify/destroy the resources *you* created), or you need to give each developer their own AWS Account to treat as a 'sandbox' where nobody else can impact it.

An in-between option might be to **allow users to deploy AWS CloudFormation stacks** that can create infrastructure but (generally) does not allow existing infrastructure to be impacted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes, You can achieve it by Adding a Bucket Policy.

Open Bucket > Permissions > Bucket Policy

Then Add Policy Similar to below:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:user/USERNAME"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME"
        ]

    }]
}
```

This Policy Denies Access to the bucket for the user, even if the user has Admin Permissions.

Comment: Thank you. S3 was just an example, one could replace S3 bucket with a DB/EC2 instance or a Lambda function or ...

Comment: Yeah, We can do this with S3 only, no idea about other Services, I think it's not possible.